# Importing my own python modules into vs.code

Tags: python, module

I'm relatively new to coding and taking an online course in python, I have come to a part that has left me scratching my head on how to get it to work.

I am trying to import my own custom module or python file in VS code to my main script and am having issues doing so. Currently this is the setup:

Ahh my apolgies. Currently the code is formatted as such

Main file:

```
import my_module
print(my_module.pi)
```

mymodule file

```
pi = 3.14
```

error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

The tutorial / online video from the course I am watching uses repl.it so I assume they have an automatic means of importing.

I am wondering how do I set this up so I can import modules / other /py files to my main file?

EDIT:

Thanks to the answer fixed it. Had it in the wrong folder.

Comment: Could you please provide you project dcitionary/file structure? And how do you run you script? And what python version are you using?

Comment: Hi! I've edited the post with a picture of my issue. I was trying to do it as the example shows, in regards to file structure i have both files saved in a same folder on desktop. 

Sorry if that isn't helpful but still new to this! Also Python 3.9.1

Comment: [Don't post an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your code and error message. Post your code and error mesage.

Comment: Ahh my apolgies. Currently the code is formatted as such

Main file:
import my_module
print(my_module.pi)

mymodule file
pi = 3.14

error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'

Comment: It's OK. You can edit your question to include your code and error message. See [how to format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: The problem most probably is caused by running python from a different folder, not where your files are located. You most probably can fix it in the interpreter setting of your VS

Comment: Ahh ok so how do I got about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize but I cannot post comments just yet however I believe I can help. First I wanted to say that you shouldn't see a error message like such unless you misspelled or misplace the .py file. Double check that your files are in the same folder

Comment: As I said in a comment, you can get message like that if working directory is different from directory the files are located.

Comment: OH my god I can't believe that was it. Thank you so much. I didn't even think to check that!

Was racking my brain trying to figure out if there was a plugin or something I had missed.

Comment: Thanks lads, to the both of ye, wasn't sure to even check that as stated. Really helped there. @YevhenKuzmovych yeah I wasn't sure what was meant by that but I glanced it and found it in the end. Thanks for all the help editing up the post too! Do either of ye guys know how I can archive this question or something not sure how to!

Answer (score 0):

When executing python it will look in the specified locations in **sys.path** in order to find your imports. If you get module not found, it's because the module you are trying to access is not located in any of the sys.path directories.

**In order to reach the module you can:**

- Add the directory of your module to the environment variable **PYTHONPATH**, telling python where to look for modules outside the default places
- Move the module to the same directory, or a sub-directory of the location of your main file, since when executing the main file, its directory is part of sys.path

this would make the module accessible in your code.